# How to set alignment of array in SSBO

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In a compute shader I have a struct for a particle:

```
struct Particle {
    float delta;
    float start_posx;
    float start_posy;
    float start_posz;
    float restart;
    uint max_textures;
    float max_lifetime;
};
```

Now I want to use this struct in an SSBO:

```
layout (std430, binding = 12) buffer particleBlock {
    Particle particles[];
};
```

I am assuming my particles in the ssbo are tightly packed, because all struct members are size of 4. If I set alignment to 16:

```
layout (std430, binding = 12) buffer particleBlock {
    layout(align = 16) Particle particles[];
};
```

will particles[1] be at offset 32? I'm not sure how this align works for arrays and this doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single array elements can't be aligned by an `align` qualifier. Only the start of the array can be aligned.

[GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; 4.4.5. Uniform and Shader Storage Block Layout Qualifiers; page 85](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf) :

> The align qualifier makes the start of each block member have a minimum byte alignment. It does not affect the internal layout within each member, which will still follow the std140 or std430 rules.
> ...
> **When align is applied to an array, it affects only the start of the array, not the array’s internal stride.**

If you would use the **std140** qualifier, an array of the struct `Particle` would have a stride of 32, because the stride is rounded up to a multiple of the base alignment of a `vec4`, which is 16.

Note, a major difference between the **std140** and **std430** standard is, that the stride of array elements is not rounded up to a multiple of 16 bytes, in case of std430.

If the struct `Particle` should have a size of 32 bytes, then you can add a dummy member at the end:

```
struct Particle {
    float delta;        //  0
    float start_posx;   //  4
    float start_posy;   //  8
    float start_posz;   // 12
    float restart;      // 16
    uint  max_textures; // 20
    float max_lifetime; // 24
    float dummy;        // 28: dummy member for the alignment
};
```

Comment: And is there no way to do what I tried to do there?

Comment: @RhuMage See the extension to the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 you meant std430 not std340 (2 occurences in your text)

Comment: @Juicebox Yes of course. What a pity. Many Thanks.